how to align the items in the navbar ?? Using html and Bootstrap5
I want to create nabvar,with logo on the right side of navbar and other items(Home,Contact Us,About...) towards the left. but when I try to align items, all are moving compleltely towards left. I want to place them evenly in 50% of navbar. but all items are moving completely towards the right or completely towards left.
Some please help me with this code.
     <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark mt-0 navbar-dark">
        
        <!-- Logo -->
         <a href="#" class="navbar-brand p-2">Logo</a>
         
         <!-- Button -->
        <button class="navbar-toggler" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#menu">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

         <!-- Menu -->
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="menu">
            <!-- lists -->
             <ul class=" navbar-nav ms-auto d-flex">
                <li class="nav-item list-inline-item flex-fill">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link ms-2">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item list-inline-item flex-fill">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link ms-2 ">Aboout Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item list-inline-item flex-fill">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link ms-2">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item list-inline-item flex-fill">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link ms-2">Contact</a>
                </li>
             </ul>
            <!-- End of menu -->
          </div>
     </nav>

I want to place the items(home,Contact us....) towards the right half of navbar with evenly spaced.
I have also tried me-auto | mx-auto | ms-auto. by using this them may move completely towards right or left. But I need cover the right 50% with evenly space between them.
Thank You......

from my understanding you want something like this:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark mt-0 navbar-dark">
        <!-- Menu -->
        <div class=" collapse navbar-collapse d-md-flex justify-content-center" id="menu">
            <!-- lists -->
            <ul class=" navbar-nav  d-flex">
                <li class="nav-item list-inline-item flex-fill">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link ms-2">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item list-inline-item flex-fill">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link ms-2 ">Aboout Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item list-inline-item flex-fill">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link ms-2">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item list-inline-item flex-fill">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link ms-2">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- End of menu -->
        </div>
        

        <!-- Button -->
        <button class="navbar-toggler" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#menu">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <!-- Logo -->
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand p-2">Logo</a>
    </nav>

</body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

</html>



for moving the menu to left add margin-right: ; to the tag with collapse navbar-collapse
i hope this will help you!
